# Error message when upgrading to 20.04

Tags: updates, error-handling

W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., E:The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release' no longer has a Release file.

I get this error message when trying to use the upgrade screen. I'm updating from 19.XX.
Machine is a Gigabyte MB - B450M-ds3H
AMD® Ryzen 3 2200g with radeon vega graphics × 4
AMD® Raven Graphics
Gnome 3.34.2
Memory 3.14 gb

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

Comment: Nope, and Nope.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Had to go into software updater settings and delete a few things. I eventually deleted the correct thing, so the upgrade worked fine after that.
Oh, I think the correct thing that I deleted was under "Other Software" heading, but not 100% sure.